# Implement J / K keyboard shortcuts to move forward/backward in questions feed?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, keyboard-shortcuts

I got used to using K and J to move back and forth to questions in my feed *even when one question is currently opened*, either in Facebook or other websites. I surprised myself today trying to go the the next question by pressing J in StackOverflow.

It's obviously not a major enhancement but I thought it would be a nice/fun to have, and probably not that hard to implement.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

This is *already implemented*.

Go to your profile and check the checkbox in your preferences at *Edit Profile & Settings* > *Preferences* > *Keyboard shortcuts* > *Enable keyboard shortcuts (when enabled, press ? for help)*.

In question lists, the <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> then navigate between the questions:

> [image]

Comment: I just tried it. I hadn't seen it. However, it does not work as I actually expected. While in a specific question, J would jump to the next one automatically. This shortcut does not do that. But it's taken already though so it's a completely different story now...

Comment: What would the 'next' question *be*? Same tags? In what order? That's what the question list is for, and why the navigation works only there. You can open questions in separate tabs with `SHIFT-ENTER`.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. I just had my feed and while browsing 1 question, I hoped J would just smartly switch to the next one, nothing more (as defined in my current feed rules)

Comment: Note that within a question, you also need to be able to navigate between the question and the answers on that page.