# Can't navigate to question by pressing Enter after selecting with J/K

Tags: bug, status-review, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

Vi-like navigation ([Implement J / K keyboard shortcuts to move forward/backward in questions feed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300605/implement-j-k-keyboard-shortcuts-to-move-forward-backward-in-questions-feed)) doesn't work anymore on Brave (Chromium).

When you've enabled keyboard navigation on your profile, you can navigate through question lists (on the homepage, on `/questions` and on `/search`) by pressing <kbd>J</kbd> (down) or <kbd>K</kbd> (up).

<kbd>Enter</kbd> used to open that question, but now it doesn't anymore, on:

- Windows 11: Chrome 105.0.5195.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows 11: Brave 1.43.93 Chromium: 105.0.5195.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- macOS 12.6: Brave 1.43.89 Chromium: 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Neither in regular mode nor in incognito mode (no plugins).

Related: [Announcing Design Accessibility Updates on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419586/announcing-design-accessibility-updates-on-so)

Comment: Can't repro either actually (still most likely the latest version of chromium); forgot I had to log in for keybinds to work. Whoops.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that Brave is not in the [supported browsers list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support) ([visualisation](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/))

Comment: I **can** reproduce this both here on meta and on SO.  Chrome 105.0.5195.102

Comment: Weird. What Stack Overflow revision are you two on? I'm on 2022.9.15.42976

Comment: @Henry same with Chrome, of which version 105 was released two weeks ago yet isn't mentioned on that visualization page. Am I too bleeding edge for once?

Comment: rev 2022.9.15.42976 for meta. i don't see anything off in the devtools yet

Comment: @Zoe same revision. I think this happened to manifest about two weeks ago on Mac, can't verify that now.

Comment: and... disabling my blockers had no effect, otherwise i have no userscripts

Comment: it is loading, i was able to inspect it for the event handler

Comment: That file loads fine, @Henry!

Comment: yeah i can't make heads or tails of it with this minified code, pressing enter does go into the keyboard events handlers, same as j and k, past that... i dunno. Calls .trigger on a DelayedEvent, then nothing else happens.

Comment: The [unminified](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/keyboard-shortcuts.en.js) is also available @KevinB if that helps.

Comment: Also reproduced it on Firefox 103.0.2 - navigating with keyboard shortcuts and pressing enter does not open the highlighted post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the meantime, don't know when.